# What's the opposite of eye candy?

Tags: phrases, antonyms

What's the opposite of eye candy?

I heard someone say, "Eye broccoli," but that's not very accurate to those of us who love broccoli. Any other ideas?

Comment: "Scratch-your-eyes-out ugly"

Comment: [Fugly](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/fugly)!

Comment: Surely you wouldn't have a problem with "eye okra"?

Comment: Or "eye scream"?

Comment: Opposite in what sense? Are we simply talking about something especially ugly, or a feature (of software for example) that is unceremoniously functional?

Comment: @SvenYargs I love okra!

Comment: Software interfaces are getting carried away in the extreme with tawdry visual frippery, and it gets called called "eye candy". There really ought to be a pejorative for pointless excessive flashiness. Maybe if it were possible to say a thing is "full of X", developers could understand the contempt some hold for such nonsense. "Eyesore", while accurate, doesn't seem to scratch this itch.

Comment: eye candyfloss? distractors?

Comment: "Eye candy corn" (because [candy corn](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Candy_corn) is probably the worst excuse for candy ever)

Comment: Ear ipecac? (The question is somewhat underspecified.)

Answer (score 75, accepted):

Eyesore?  Affront to all that is holy?  Mirror-cracker?

Comment: +1 for the colourful 'mirror-cracker'.

Comment: my 10 year old read this and immediately said eye-poop...

Answer (score 13):

"Eye Candy" is [most often applied to people](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/eye%20candy). In that case, the opposite is "Double Bagger".

Paraphrasing [the *Urban Dictionary* entry (vulgar)](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Double%20Bagger) -- which [the term predates by up to 60 years](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=double%20bagger&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3):

> **Double Bagger**:
>   A (person) so ugly that (making love to) (him or her) is only possibly(sic) with the use of two bags: One over (his/her) head, and a second bag over your own head in case (his/her) bag falls off.

---

In the general case, "Eyesore" is common, [as *idunno* answered](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/217975/20655).
But I prefer: **"A blight for sore eyes"** (^_^)

Comment: "Eye candy" is frequently used within the design community to denote something that has no other purpose other than making thing appear prettier. Personally, I have heard "Eye candy" applied to interface elements much more than to people.

Comment: In the first person shooter game community, all the best graphics are known as "eye candy". If you don't have the latest and greatest video adapter, you might need to turn off some of the eye candy to make your system run the game faster.

Answer (score 13):

The term "eyesore" is well established. It is usually applied to buildings, but it could be used do describe pretty much anything that is unpleasant to look at.

> That old office block is a real eyesore.

Answer (score 0):

Like many terms, this could have many opposites, depending on the sense you have in mind.

"Eye candy" can simply mean a person or object that is pretty, or it can mean a person or object that serves no purpose other than to be pretty.

In the first case, "opposite" could mean someone who is not particularly pretty or attention getting, e.g. "plain". Or it could mean someone incredibly ugly.

In the second case, "opposite" could again mean something ugly. Or it could mean something that is pretty but also serves a useful purpose. Or it could mean something that is not pretty but instead serves a useful purpose.

Answer (score -1):

Butt Ugly is normally considered the opposite of eye candy.

Comment: It's fine as an adjective, but the questioner seems to be asking for a noun.

Answer (score -5):

EyeScream works perfectly opposite EyeCandy   ----Eyes are visual both are treats --but one does not leave a good taste in the mouth   ;

Comment: What are you talking about?

Comment: @DCShannon It's a pun.  "EyeScream" -> Ice Cream

Comment: -1, I don't think a joke with a made-up word really counts as an answer. Have you ever heard anyone use this word in any context?

Comment: @DCShannon: Not as a word (neither is "eye candy" a single word), but it *might* be a reference to http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EyeScream, although I note that the trope refers to something completely different from what the question is asking.

Comment: Also, I don't know about you, but on a site like English Language & Usage I'd expect reviewers to know what an *answer* to a question is. This is very obviously an answer, not a critique or a request for clarification. Whether it's a serious answer or a flippant one is probably a separate matter entirely.

Answer (score -5):

Beer goggles.  The problem doesn't lie with the other person, it lies with your perception of that person.  Therefore, drinking an intoxicating beverage that lowers your inhibitions changes your perception of that person.

Comment: Welcome to [ELU.SE] @Fredrick. I don't think this answers the question. Please see the [help].