# What does "that's what" mean?

Tags: meaning, phrases

I heard many people saying this, but I couldn't really understand what they meant to say:

> That's what I am saying.

Answer (score 1):

That's what I'm saying is normally used in an argument to say literally that's what I'm saying, you are arguing my point

Comment: I cant not enough reputation

Comment: Do You know what I mean here @Queue21

Comment: OH sorry now I understand I fixed it

Answer (score 1):

"That's what I'm saying" or "That's what I'm talking about" can mean different things in different contexts.

- You are in an argument with someone else when you realize you are saying the same thing, just in different ways. You'll say "That's what I am saying" (perhaps said meekly).
- A group of people, including you, are having some discussion and you agree very much with something that some other person just said. You'll say "That's what I'm saying!" as an alternative to "I agree completely!"
- You and some friends go to a nightclub, where the nightlife is rather lame and every member of your sexual preference represents the [antonym of eye candy](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/217970/whats-the-opposite-of-eye-candy). You convince your friends to go another club, whereupon immediately a very nice example of what you think of as eye candy walks by. You turn to your friends and say "Now that's what I'm talking about!"

A final example: I grew up ten miles from a ski area. I don't remember not being able to ski. Then I moved to Houston, Texas. Later when I took my sons to a ski area, they wanted to snowboard. Knowing only how to use two boards, I put my sons in a class. I greeted them as they came out of the class and took them down what I thought was a very easy slope. My sons all took the very slow and cautious approach they were taught in class. One of them finally said "enough of this pansy stuff" and pointed straight downhill. Shortly later he dumped and tumbled. As I approached him, he stood up, dusted himself off, and exclaimed "Now THAT'S what I'm talking about!"